# Can you add a CC to a Mosaico / CiviMail / bulk Email?

Tags: civimail

I am sending a few dozen invites via mosaico and need to add a CC and maybe a BCC field to the emails.

Is there a way to do this? I know you can on regular emails sent from CiviCRM.

Comment: is another option to use Sch Reminder? it has a 'also send to' setting

Comment: Would you like to have cc'd on each email sent to a contact?